# При закрытии окна надо записать данные в файл на Си в WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

Пишу программу, надо, чтоб она при закрытии записывала кое-какие данные в файл.
Я так понимаю, делать это надо при получении сообщения, видимо, WM_DESTROY? А после завершения записи в файл надо вызвать PostQuitMessage().
Всё ли я правильно понимаю? Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Нет, вы не должны в обработчике оконного сообщения делать ничего длинного. Иначе окно зависнет.

Comment: А как же быть? Должен же быть выход.

Comment: Ну например вы можете записывать что угодно после окончания message loop'а (это который с `TranslateMessage` и `DispatchMessage`).

Comment: @0Zerro, Вам тут VladD нагнал страху на ровном месте. Вы лучше опишите подробно проблему, т.к. на Ваш вопрос "Всё ли я правильно понимаю" можно спокойно ответить "Да", если речь идет о сохранении пары Кб настроек, например. Особенно, если у Вас все необходимые данные для этого каким-то образом связаны с окном.

Comment: @mega Да, мне надо записать пару Кб настроек в файл, вы верно догадались